# Persian mobile validation number in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I search every site to find a regular expression for Iranian mobile numbers that start with
`091xxxxxxxx` or `093xxxxxxxx` or `092xxxxxxxx` or `090xxxxxxxx`   .
finally found below solution.Hope to useful for other Persian programmers.

Comment: Visit:   http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=iranian

Comment: Your refer is well too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server"  
     ControlToValidate="txtMobile" Display="Dynamic"  
     ErrorMessage="Enter a valid number" ValidationExpression="^09[0-3][0-9]{8}$">    
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```